# kml: Plot graph/curves in a description ballon on google earth

Tags: google-maps, plot, kml, google-earth, curve

Is it possible to plot graph or curves (**not images or photos**) inside the description ballon of a placemark on google earth, using .kml file?

I have data about a placemark, for example statistic data like evolution of the number of the population of a town and I want to plot curve showing that evolution **dynamically**, on the placemark description ballon.

Is it possible? Any idea? Other alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I just have no idea about how to do that or what tag to use in my .kml file for that